# Is $R_\mathfrak{p}$ local when $R$ is noncommutative?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, local-rings

This may seem like a basic question but I can't seem to find any good texts on the matter (perhaps someone can suggest any?). Basically I have a noncommutative ring $R$ with prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. Obviously if $R$ was commutative then $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a local ring. I was wondering if the same holds true for a noncommutative ring.

Comment: Here are some notes on the subject: https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/adbell/www/Research/locnotes.pdf

Comment: In particular see the paragraph following Corollary 2.2.

Comment: First, let me ask: are you doing traditional localization at a kind of multiplicative set? And if so, are you aware of the conditions such a set must satisfy? One can't naively localize at every prime ideal of a noncommutative ring.

Comment: Thanks @JohnM, those notes were great.

Comment: @rschwieb YesI am aware of the conditions that these sort of sets must satisfy.

Comment: @SamWilliams Then it might be good to say "for a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $R\setminus \mathfrak{p}$ is a right denominator set " or something, since it does not work for all primes. It's a pretty strong condition, even stronger than "completely prime."